# Optimizing NumPy script that calculates Normal Distribution

Tags: python, numpy

I wrote the following NumPy-Python test script to get the normal distribution of certain inputs. I think I may not be using NumPy's vector operations efficiently to process the input data.
Can you show me the NumPy way of processing the inputs?

```
import numpy as np

#Inputs
mu = np.array( [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], dtype='uint8' )
sigma = np.array( [1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3.] )
number = np.array( [ 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 25, 20, 15, 10, 5 ], dtype='uint16' )

#Processing
np.random.seed(0)
norms = [  np.random.normal(i, sigma[n], number[n]) for n, i in enumerate(mu) ]
print( norms )

a = np.concatenate( [ np.ceil(i) for i in norms ] )
print( a )

#Output
result = np.histogram( a, bins=np.arange(np.amin(a), np.amax(a)+1, 1, dtype='uint8' ) )
print( result )
```

Comment: If you really want to vectorize this, you can do something like [this](https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html) maybe. But this looks all right to be. I would just merge the concat operation when I am constructing the norms array

Comment: Normally--- accidental pun here--- we would want to make multiple draws from the same distribution, from a distribution with a fixed `mu` and `sigma`, as with, say, Monte Carlo simulations. Thus the Numpy folk have not set us up with a `np.random.normal` that takes vector values of `mu` and `sigma` as inputs. I don't see how the use of a loop could be avoided with vectorized `mu` and `sigma` inputs. Note in this regard that the link offered by @pecey indeed states that the performance will be the same as with a for loop.

Comment: @pecey as stated in the link, `np.vectorize` is just a fancy name for what OP already did.

Comment: I wasn't aware of that. Thank you @MikeO'Connor and @Quang. I would add one point to @Mike's comment. If we want the same number of values, then there we can infact pass list of means and sd. The shape would be `[number of examples, len(means)]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to vectorize your code is to generate the random standard normal sample and scale accordingly:

```
np.random.seed(0)

# random samples
samples = np.random.normal(size=number.sum())

# scale
samples = samples*sigma.repeat(number) + mu.repeat(number)

# equivalent to your `a`
out = np.ceil(samples)

# visualize to compare output:
fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 2)

axes[0].hist(out, bins=np.arange(out.min(), out.max()+1))
axes[0].set_title('my code')

axes[1].hist(a, bins=np.arange(a.min(), a.max()+1))
axes[1].set_title('yours')
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Your `mu` only has 9 values, your `sigma` and `number` each has 10. Is it intentional?

Comment: My bad. I just noticed the typo in my question too. ;) Trying to understand your scaling approach as it is new to me. Can you explain this or point me to a documentation on it? really cool....

Comment: Basically, `N(mu, sigma) ~ N(0,1) * sigma + mu`. Now, `mu.repeat(number)` repeat each `mu` value the corresponding `number` of time. So `mu.repeat(number)` starts with `5` values `1` and `10` values `2`.

Comment: I could not get matplotlib to show the correct results as you have. I have updated my question to show my issue. Can you tell me what is wrong? Your approach is faster.

Comment: @Did you forget to reset random seed in my approach? Although the histogram printouts do look exactly the same.

Comment: Opps...I thought seeding it once was sufficient. Reseeding the random generator before your script resolved the discrepancy in matplotlib... cheers.